Подключение к WMI по локальной сети без ввода логина и пароля
Надо с основной ОС Windows 11 подключиться к виртуальной Windows XP (oracle virtual box).
Я подключаюсь с помощью этой команды (надо ввести данные учетной записи виртуальной ос):
$creds = Get-Credential


Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile -ComputerName 192.168.56.101 -Credential $creds


Мне нужно подключаться к WMI виртуальной ОС без ввода данных учетной записи. Если запустить команду Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName 192.168.56.101, пишет отказано в доступе.
В настройках WMI я пытался добавить разрешения пользователя основной ОС. но там его не было. CHAT GPT4 подсказал добавить анонимный вход. Если что брандмауэр полностью отключен на Windows XP. Помогите пожаааалуйста

Это мне для курсовой надо. Нужно организовать сбор данных о входе пользователей с помощью WMI.

Если я правильно помню, XP запрещает такое использование WMI из под гостя, ДАЖЕ если вы разрешили ему полный доступ. Надо прописывать policy, а если домен - то еще и соответствующие policy.
